# Recaptcha prevents login with session cookie using c++ libcurl

Tags: curl, recaptcha

First, I am not a web-dev and am mostly trying to teach myself by searching through networkanalysis browser logs, cookies, and curl docs.

Using libcurl in C++, I've written a program some months ago to handle requests for a page that requires logging in. To avoid having to deal with having to log in with code (which I don't really understand how to do yet), I opted to simply log in with my browser (Firefox), identify the session cookie, and then load the cookie from the Firefox cookie database in my code. Like:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
auto handle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, ""); // activate cookie engine
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, firefox_cookie);
std::string buf;
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buf);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 
    [](void* chunk, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* buf) {
        const size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
        static_cast<std::string*>(buf)->append(static_cast<char*>(chunk), realsize);
        return realsize;
    });
if (curl_easy_perform(handle)) std::cout << "failed\n";
curl_global_cleanup();

do_something(buf);
```

**Everything has worked up until now**, but recently it stopped working and I now get a page telling me "complete the captcha" as response. As far as I can tell from logs, google recaptcha is used, but that is about all I understand here..

However, when logging in with the browser, I never have to complete any captcha .. I am lost here as I don't see at all how this works or why the result in the browser is different from the code. I already copied the full header from the browser log

```
// add this after setting the cookie in the code above
struct curl_slist* list = NULL;
list = curl_slist_append(list, R"(Key: value)");
// and more ..
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
```

but I still get this "complete the captcha" result. So I am (unless the logs are hiding something?) sending the exact same request from the code as from the browser, yet I get a different response.
There is no other GET / POST or anything happening before this. When I clear the log and refresh the page, this is the first request sent by the browser.

- What information am I missing? Is the set of key/values in the header + cookies not the whole request?
- How do I make this work, i.e. "complete the captcha" in the code, that is invisible and silently/automatically completed in the browser?

I realize a captcha is made to prevent bots from logging in, but not only is there not actually any captcha in the browser, I am also fine manually logging in, as long as I can then use the session in my code. In other words - the browser can do it without human interaction, so clearly it is possible to do in code. So how e.g. would I do this if I wanted to write a browser? Would code for that not also use curl?

Comment: I would guess google has some server side code that is smart enough to see the difference between your browser and your curl program, prompting the captcha. What exactly are you trying to log in to? You should probably do it "properly" instead of trying to find a way to work your way around it.

Comment: My first trigger for bot activity would be "is the user agent submitting a login form without loading it or its dependent resources first?" Also, if the site's owners put a recaptcha in, they generally do not want people to access it programmatically. Are you sure you're not breaking the terms and conditions? Is there no API you can use instead?

Comment: @super I would think something like this, but then I would expect more requests to be sent to do those other things, and not get the response I want with a single request and a single cookie? I am trying to log into pixiv.net/

Comment: @Botje I did not find a documented API on the site, but there are apps for it so assume it exists somewhere ..? There are plently of requests that give practical json responses too, so probably part of the API? But I'm also very new to understanding these.

Comment: I found out that the site changed their cookies, somehow there are two variants, one which uses that captcha and one which does not - it works again after using the new one. My original question however is still unclear to me - what can be different in browser (which still works with the old version) vs code - so I won't post this an answer.

Comment: Same answer: different behavior in fetching pages, or different timing. It's doing what it's supposed to do: prevent bot behavior.